# Trouble toggling WebAudio API node assignments with a button function

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

Below I have a function called **buttonClickResult** that is launched when a user clicks an image. I would like the click on/off to reassign the variable called **distortionSwitch** between two values. One is called **emptyCable** and the other is called **overdrive**. This variable is inside the function called **bufferFunctionName**

I don't quite know how to pass this variable assignment to the other function.

To summarize when a user clicks the button the variable inside **bufferFunctionName**  called **distortionSwitch** should toggle between a variable assignment called **emptyCable** and one called **overdrive**

Thank you.

```
 var humSnd = new Audio('audio/hum.wav');
 var button = document.getElementById('btn1');

 buttonClickResult = function () {
   function playClickSound(filename) {
     var snd = new Audio(filename);
     snd.play();
   }


   button.onmousedown = function buttonClicked() {

     if (button.className == "off") {
       button.className = "on";
       button.src = 'imgs/on.png';
       playClickSound('audio/click.wav');
       humSnd.play();
       humSnd.loop = true;


     } else if (button.className == "on") {
       button.className = "off";
       button.src = 'imgs/off.png';
       playClickSound('audio/click.wav');
       humSnd.pause();


     }

   }
 };

 buttonClickResult();






 var context = new webkitAudioContext();


 // Start Of Web Audio API Buffer & Playback Abstraction

 function audioApiKey(domNode, fileDirectory, bufferFunctionName, incomingBuffer, savedBuffer, xhr) {

   this.domNode = domNode;
   this.fileDirectory = fileDirectory;
   this.bufferFunctionName = bufferFunctionName;
   this.incomingBuffer = incomingBuffer;
   this.savedBuffer = savedBuffer;
   this.xhr = xhr;


   bufferFunctionName = function () {
     var distortionSwitch = overdrive; // THIS SHOULD TOGGLE

     var source = context.createBufferSource();
     source.buffer = savedBuffer;
     source.connect(distortionSwitch.input);

     distortionSwitch.connect(delay.input);

     delay.connect(convolver.input);
     convolver.connect(context.destination);
     source.noteOn(0); // Play sound immediately
   };
```

**addendum**
When I write the code below **bufferFunctionName** can't access **distortionSwitch** even though it's scoped in a manner that it should ( I think?)

```
var distortionSwitch = overdrive;     

bufferFunctionName = function () {   
  var source = context.createBufferSource();
  source.buffer = savedBuffer;
  source.connect(distortionSwitch.input);

  distortionSwitch.connect(delay.input);

  delay.connect(convolver.input);
  convolver.connect(context.destination);
  source.noteOn(0); // Play sound immediately
};
```

When I write it like this it works fine

```
bufferFunctionName = function () {  

  var distortionSwitch = overdrive;  

  var source = context.createBufferSource();
  source.buffer = savedBuffer;
  source.connect(distortionSwitch.input);

  distortionSwitch.connect(delay.input);

  delay.connect(convolver.input);
  convolver.connect(context.destination);
  source.noteOn(0); // Play sound immediately
};
```

Comment: Your code is very confusing because your indentation is wildly inconsistent.

Comment: Sorry I cleaned it up . Please remove downvote

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, I think what you want to do is to move this line:

```
var distortionSwitch = overdrive;
```

and put it up top with

```
var humSnd = new Audio('audio/hum.wav');
var button = document.getElementById('btn1');
var distortionSwitch = overdrive;
```

This makes the distortionSwitch available within the button click listener. You then do

```
if (button.className == "off") {
   button.className = "on";
   button.src = 'imgs/on.png';
   distortionSwitch = overdrive;
   playClickSound('audio/click.wav');
   humSnd.play();
   humSnd.loop = true;
 } else if (button.className == "on") {
   button.className = "off";       
   button.src = 'imgs/off.png';
   distortionSwitch = emptyCable;
   playClickSound('audio/click.wav');
   humSnd.pause();
 }
```

Comment: What you write makes sense and I tried it but something is weird with the scoping. I tried to clarify by adding an addendum to my question.

Comment: Hm. Looks like it should work to me. What kind of error do you get? I'd probably need to see the code in context to help you any further. @Taoist

Comment: Thanks, I actually found a solution and it entailed moving an if statement around. I don't want to bore you with the details but I am still perplext by why I had to fix it the way I did. Thanks regardless. Always appreciated.